# Auto-filling radio buttons

Tags: javascript, autofill

Not sure if this is an appropriate forum to ask this question, but I've run out of options.

For a class, we have to take 300+ question tests, but we get to take them an infinite amount of times.  I was wondering if there was a program that could intelligently save the status of radio buttons based on the questions asked so that I don't have to go through each question answering them one-by-one.

In case that wasn't clear: Each new time you take the test, it doesn't save what your answer was for the previous submission.  I want a way that can auto-fill all the radio buttons based on the previous submission.

I tried an auto_fill extension, but those all of those worked based upon the javascript name of the button (which changes each time).  Is there any solution?

Comment: which server side language u r using ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.  I just want a link to a program or an extension that can save the values of radio button data based on multiple choice questions that are given to me.

Comment: @User372526: There is no magic! you have to say what is your server side language do you use any cms for that ? how do you create the question forms so the folks here can answer your question.

Comment: the radio data is stored using javascript

Comment: google for a "form filler" or "selenium" will do the trick too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you've said this is the type of code I would start with..
Paste into the address bar of your browser on a page with radio buttons:

```
javascript:(function(){var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");for (var i=0; i<inputElements.length; i++) {if (inputElements[i].getAttribute('type') == 'radio') {inputElements[i].checked = true;}}})();
```

(readable version):

```
(function(){
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i=0; i<inputElements.length; i++) {
        if (inputElements[i].getAttribute('type') == 'radio') {
            inputElements[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
})();
```

This code sets every radio button to checked, but as only one radio button in each group can be selected, the actual result is that the last radio button in each group is selected. Not particularly useful, but I would probably need more details about the structure of the radio buttons (how many per question) to come up with anything better.

Taking it further, code could be written to run after you have filled in all the radio buttons once; this code would generate more code which would fill in the radio buttons for you subsequent times.

Of course, this is only a "sensible" solution to pursue if your school computers are "locked down" and you can't do much with them.